# php - ignore files missing from directory

Tags: php, html

I am calling a php script with html to randomly display images from a directory. I want to add img1.jpg through img50.jpg to the php file, even though some of those files don't exist yet, so that a client can add images to a directory at their leisure. 
Currently, if one of those files doesn't exist, the image is still called and displays as a missing file.

How do I check if the file exists, and then ignore it if it's missing?

Here's the current php code:

```
    <?php 

// rotate images randomly but w/o dups on same page - format: 

// <img src='rotate.php?i=0'> - rotate image #0 - use 'i=1' 

// for second, etc 

// (c) 2004 David Pankhurst - use freely, but please leave in my credit 

$images=array( // list of files to rotate - add as needed 

  "img1.gif", 

  "img2.gif", 

  "img3.gif", 

  "img4.gif", 

  "img5.gif" ); 

$total=count($images); 

$secondsFixed=10; // seconds to keep list the same 

$seedValue=(int)(time()/$secondsFixed); 

srand($seedValue); 

for ($i=0;$i<$total;++$i) // shuffle list 'randomly' 

{ 

  $r=rand(0,$total-1); 

  $temp =$images[$i]; 

  $images[$i]=$images[$r]; 

  $images[$r]=$temp; 

} 

$index=(int)($_GET['i']); // image index passed in 

$i=$index%$total; // make sure index always in bounds 

$file=$images[$i]; 

header("Location: $file"); // and pass file reference back 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading all images you can hide those images which are not loaded,or failed to load, using following piece of jQuery code

```
$("img").error(function () { 
    $(this).hide();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While parsing that array of yours, check whether the image exists or not using this function.

PS: you need to define the path of the image.

```
if (is_array(getimagesize($absolute_image)))
    return true; // image exist
else
    return false;
```